# Can you make a div draggable using $.ui.draggable()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, jquery-ui-draggable, userscripts

I'm having trouble getting `$('#id').draggable()` to work when I insert it into an html page using my Greasemonkey user script. Is there a way to make something draggable using $.ui.draggable() instead? What I want is something like:

```
$.ui.draggable(document.getElementById('id'), {'option': 'value'});
```

Here's the part where I insert the jQuery:

```
if (!document.getElementById('ccst1')) {
    var ccst1 = document.createElement("script");
    ccst1.id = "ccst1";
    ccst1.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
    ccst1.type = "text/javascript";
    document.head.appendChild(ccst1);
    var ccst2 = document.createElement("script");
    ccst2.id = "ccst2";
    ccst2.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js";    
    ccst2.type = "text/javascript";
    document.head.appendChild(ccst2);
    var ccst3 = document.createElement("script");
    ccst3.id = "ccst3";
    ccst3.src = "http://yourjavascript.com/3314922191/jquery.scrollTo-min.js";
    ccst3.type = "text/javascript";
    document.head.appendChild(ccst3);
    var ccst4 = document.createElement("script");
    ccst4.id = "ccst4";
    ccst4.type = "text/javascript";
    ccst4.innerHTML = "$(function(){$('#ccpanelmassiveconstruct').draggable({'handle': '#ccpmchandle', 'constrain': 'parent', 'distance': 20, 'cursor': 'move', 'grid': [10,10], 'scroll': true});$('#concealediframe').resizable();$('#ccpmctabs').tabs();});";
    document.head.appendChild(ccst4);
}
```

EDIT: When I use the Firebug console to test things out, it recognizes that $ and jQuery exist, and it recognizes that $.ui exists, and it recognizes that $.ui.draggable exists. But when I try to make something draggable with $('id').draggable() it fails with "$ is not defined" error.

Thanks!

Comment: Any idea why `$("#draggable").draggable();` doesn't work?

Comment: Have you checked the JavaScript console for errors? Are you *certain* that you're including jQuery in the greasemonkey script?

Comment: we're gonna ned more code to see what's wrong

Comment: in your gm script, do you write `<script>$('#id').draggable();</script>` **after** inserting your new div? (the one with the "id" id ) (and are you sure that "id" is a unique id?)

Comment: ok, I'm updating the question to include some of my code. Joseph: I have no idea. @BobbyJack: I've included it in the html page, not the actual script. It returns a "$ is not defined" error, but I've looked that up, and it's not because the library isn't loading. Other jQuery and jQueryUI works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, I've solved my problem. I think this might be a topic related to other I saw on forums for Userscripts.org, so if anybody is interested in my solution, here it is.

The problem did, in fact, have to do with jQuery not being loaded, and then jQuery UI trying to call on that before it was loaded, and then other things trying to call on jQuery UI without THAT being loaded. Here's the working code I'm using now:

```
var ccst1 = document.createElement("script");
ccst1.id = "ccst1";
ccst1.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
ccst1.type = "text/javascript";
document.body.appendChild(ccst1);
function ccst2func() {
    var ccst2 = document.createElement("script");
    ccst2.id = "ccst2";
    ccst2.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js";
    ccst2.type = "text/javascript";
    document.body.appendChild(ccst2);
    ccst2.addEventListener("load", ccst4func, true);
}
ccst1.addEventListener("load", ccst2func, true);

document.body.insertBefore(concealerPanel, document.body.firstChild);

function ccst4func() {
    var ccst4 = document.createElement("script");
    ccst4.id = "ccst4";
    ccst4.type = "text/javascript";
    ccst4.innerHTML = "$('#ccpanelmassiveconstruct').draggable({'handle': '#ccpmchandle', 'constrain': 'parent', 'distance': 20, 'cursor': 'move', 'grid': [10,10], 'scroll': true});\n$('#iframeDragger').resizable();\n$('#ccpmctabs').tabs();";
    document.body.appendChild(ccst4);
}
```

Thanks to Joey Geralnik for that solution.